# How do you set CiviCRM to be the default page for users in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

In Drupal, you can go to **Configuration menu > Site Information** and set http://mysite.org/civicrm to be the default front page.  That way, once a user is authenticated, they're dropped right on to the CiviCRM dashboard.  How do you perform an equivalent task in Wordpress?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try Peter's Login Redirect to set the landing page to /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM after successful authentication.

see https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/

Comment: That worked perfectly and took two minutes to set up, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you didn't want to install a plugin, you could also add a redirect directly to functions.php in your theme. Something like the below would let you redirect only administrators to CiviCRM.

```
function civicrm_login_redirect( $url, $request, $user ){
    if( $user && is_object( $user ) && is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
        if( $user->has_cap( 'administrator' ) ) {
            $url = admin_url( 'admin.php?page=CiviCRM', 'https' );
        } else {
            $url = home_url('/some-landing-page/');
        }
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'civicrm_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect

Answer (score 1):

There is also a plugin available in the WordPress Repository that allows you to set redirects depending on WP user roles. 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/login-with-ajax/